# Only show result of current year in gridview

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

```
protected void loadCandidate()
{
        int currentyear = DateTime.Now.Year;

        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select studentID, name, faculty,position,year,candidateImage from candidate where year =2020", con);

        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows == true)
        {
            gvhistory.DataSource = dr;
            gvhistory.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I want to show the selected column data when the year equals the current year automatically without changing it manually. I had tried the `select * from table where YEAR(year) = YEAR(CURDATE())` but the grid view are empty even though there are records in the database which year are equals to 2020

Comment: Just curious, how would `YEAR(year)` differ from `year`

Comment: FWIW, `year = YEAR(CURDATE())` works just fine for me

Comment: I'm not sure but in this case the year are referred to column year

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the constant value 2020 with a parameter placeholder, then add the parameter to the parameters collection of the MySqlCommand

```
protected void loadCandidate()
{
    int currentyear = DateTime.Now.Year;

    string cmdText = @"select studentID, name, faculty,position,year,candidateImage 
                       from candidate 
                       where year = @yr"

    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@yr", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = currentyear;
    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows == true)
    {
        gvhistory.DataSource = dr;
        gvhistory.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Said that I cannot not notice that you are using a global connection object. As already explained thousands times this is very bad for the resource usage on your server. Always use a local connection object, read the connection string from your config file and then dispose the connection

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
{
    ..... use your connection and then at the brace exit the connection is disposed
}
```